# can't connect with Putty after editing configuration of SSH

Tags: ssh, debian, putty

I was editing PuTTY's config file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I didn't know how to save the file (:w and :q) so I quit PuTTY. It crashed the file so I reopened and saved it.

But now PuTTY tells me:

`Access denied.`

I rebooted the server in safe mode (or something like that - netboot system I think). How can I reset the configuration of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Comment: need for information from you. WHAT file were you editting? you weren't editting putty's configuration, since it is a windows program, and `:w` and `:q` are commands for `vim` an editor in linux. so what file were you changing? `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ?

Comment: i was editing : /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: What where the changes you made?

Comment: no idea. i was adding : Port 1337                  # Changer le port par défaut 

Protocol 2                 
AllowUsers dew

I UPDATED THE POST, please read :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you acknowledged you were modifying `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` over ssh, and you screwed up the file, and for some reason `sshd` restarted, you're SOL, since i presume you /only/ have remote access.

if you have `plesk` or `cpanel` or some other web interface that allows you to download/upload system files, edit system files, or even reset to default the system files, that would be your next place to look.

you could upload a new copy of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, though i don't know how to guide you through a control panel interface, and then restart `sshd` on the server, or if you can edit the files or restore to default to fix your errors.

beyond that, you will have to contact their support and ask that they reset the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart the ssh server for you.

to fix your problems, you will want to modify the file and undo the changes you did, and find any syntax errors. you can find syntax errors by running `/usr/bin/ssh -t` which will check for correctness.

in another response, it sounds like you changed the default port, have you tried connecting to your host, specifying /that/ port in putty?

Comment: i only, now have access to a netboot system with utilities like testdis, parted, mdam, makedev,grub, lsof......... (and a lot more).

I don't have CPanel or Plesk, but i can reset my server. Is this that important so i can reset the server ?

Comment: if /you/ have no way to access your server, and fix the files, then you will have to contact customer support for your host.

Comment: crap, didn't know it was so messed up to screw one line of a cfg file.
Hopefully, i didn't put my website on it. Thanks

Comment: having customer support fix the issue is a better solution to wiping the system and starting fresh, especially if you have put any amount of work into setting up the server. it would be a simple fix for them to just reset your `sshd_config`